# Is there a way to find out whether a cell is being used elsewhere in Excel 2003

Tags: excel

I have a rather large workbook and I'm mainly looking to determine which fields I don't use that I can prune out of the report for maintenance purposes. Is there a way to click on a cell and see a list of all the cells that have used it or to click on a cell and see which pivot it's referencing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want 'trace dependents/precedents'...not sure exactly where it's located in Excel 2003, as it's been a while.

Comment: +1 go Tools > Formula Auditing > Trace Precedents (or Trace Dependents) as required

Answer (score 4):

In Excel 2007, if you click on a cell, then go to the formulas tab in the Ribbon, there is an icon for tracing dependecies. Arrows will appear to show you all cells that reference that cell.

Comment: It's in excel 2003 and I can't seem to find that ribbon.

Comment: Check out the comment left by barrowc on the other answer :)

Comment: Yup! Got it! Have some upboats!

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2013 this function is found under the FORMULAS tab.

[image]

Trace Dependents is likely what you want.